# PHP: Return string between two characters

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, keyword

I am wanting to use "keywords" within a large string.  These keywords start and end using *my_keyword* and are user defined.  How, within a large string, can I search and find what is between the two * characters and return each instance?

The reason it might change it, that parts of the keywords can be user defined, such as *page_date_Y* which might show the year in which the page was created.

So, again, I just need to do a search and return what is between those * characters. Is this possible, or is there a better way of doing this if I don't know the "keyword" length or what i might be?

Comment: I found a super nice function that does just what I want, but, I want to put all the found keywords into an array. http://www.justin-cook.com/wp/2006/03/31/php-parse-a-string-between-two-strings/  Does anyone have tips on how I could modify that script?

Comment: I hope the user can't define a keyword with a * in it  ;)

Comment: I am using the function in the above link u have given and its working fine for me....

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->between('*', '*')`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L412) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
<?php
// keywords are between *
$str = "PHP is the *best*, its the *most popular* and *I* love it.";    
if(preg_match_all('/\*(.*?)\*/',$str,$match)) {            
        var_dump($match[1]);            
}
?>
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "best"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "most popular"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "I"
}
```

Comment: Brilliant!  And so simple.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Explode on "*"

```
$str = "PHP is the *best*, *its* the *most popular* and *I* love it.";
$s = explode("*",$str);
for($i=1;$i<=count($s)-1;$i+=2){
    print $s[$i]."\n";    
}
```

output

```
$ php test.php
best
its
most popular
I
```

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go:

```
function stringBetween($string, $keyword)
{
    $matches = array();
    $keyword = preg_quote($keyword, '~');

    if (preg_match_all('~' . $keyword . '(.*?)' . $keyword . '~s', $string, $matches) > 0)
    {
        return $matches[1];
    }

    else
    {
        return 'No matches found!';
    }
}
```

Use the function like this:

```
stringBetween('1 *a* 2 3 *a* *a* 5 *a*', '*a*');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract a string that's enclosed by two *different* strings (Like something in parentheses, brackets, html tags, etc.), here's a post more specific to that:

[Grabbing a String Between Different Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949029/how-can-i-get-string-between-two-characters-string-php/13206315#13206315)