# PHP - How to get the string between two specific characters

Tags: php, string, variables

I got now a two sides that contains numbers and between two specific numbers there is a string that shows a group of numbers, Let's say we got this `123456789`$numbers`1234567` and I want to get the result of `$numbers` so how can I get it?
Thanks

Comment: try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949029/how-can-i-get-string-between-two-characters-string-php

Comment: what happens if $numbers is the same as the first group of numbers or the last? eg: `$numbers = 1234567` so you'll be looking in `12345678912345671234567`

Comment: @kennypu  Ok is there another way to get the characters after a Specific number?

Comment: that was just a question. if you're just using seperators, it would make more sense to just use something other than numbers. eg. `[num]$numbers[num], or |$numbers|`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We generally expect questions to show some research effort. Will you update your question to show what you have tried and explain how that attempt failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the two strings that it is sandwiched between then you can strip out the strings that you are looking for.

Not too elegant but this works:

```
$str1 = "123456789";
$str2 = "1234567";
$numberstr = "123456789";

$searchstring = "123456789".$numberstr."1234567";

$limit = 1;
$numbers = substr($searchstring, 0, strlen($searchstring) - strlen($str2)); // Remove the end of the string with length = $str2
$numbers = substr($numbers, strlen($numbers) - strlen($str1)); // Remove the most string from the beginning

print $numbers;
```

Output:

```
123456789
```

In summary, it removes the known string from the end, then the other known string from the beginning.

UPDATE: as per the comments, use two substrs to find the wanted string

Comment: your method fails if the `$numberstr = 123456789`

Comment: I would use 2 `substr`'s. Seems cleaner for me.

Comment: Good points. I was used to the java implemention where you can limit the number of replacements in str_replace. Learn something knew everyday. Thanks for the comments.