# RegEx - numbers between . and /

Tags: php, regex

I have a bunch of URL's like this. I need to get the thread id which is located between "." and "/" without getting the post number on the end of the URL.

https://www.internetforum.com/thread-title-here.111111/#post-22222222

I'd like regex to get 111111 in this example.

Can anyone help? I can't do this for the life of, I've got no issues with getting digits between two strings but I'm struggling as it's symbols here and not characters...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, what does not work in your solution?

Comment: You can use a backslash to escape the symbols, if that is of any help.

Comment: See a sample code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047337/php-return-string-between-two-characters). Put your "symbols" there with `\d+` to match digits and you are done.

Comment: Note you can do it without escaping anything  - `preg_match('~(?<=[.])[0-9]+(?=/)~', $s, $match)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
<?php

    $url = "https://www.internetforum.com/thread-title-here.111111/#post-22222222";

    preg_match("/\.([0-9]+)\//", $url, $match);

    if($match){
        echo $match[1]; // prints out 111111
    }


    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could do something like so,

```
$str = 'https://www.internetforum.com/thread-title-here.111111/#post-22222222';
preg_match('/internetforum.com\/.*?\.(.*?)\/.*/',$str,$matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without regex for example:

```
$s = 'https://www.internetforum.com/thread-title-here.111111/#post-22222222';
echo $o = explode("/",end(explode(".", $s)))[0];
```